Negation of WARP
I wanted to write the negation of WARP.
The following is the definition of WARP from Microeconomic Theory by Andreu Mas-Colell, Whinston and Green:
The Walrasian demand function $x(p,w)$ satisfies the weak axiom of revealed preferences if the following property holds for any two price-wealth situations $(p,w)$ and $(p',w')$:
If $p.x(p',w') \leq w$ and $x(p',w') \neq x(p,w)$ then $p'.x(p,w)>w'$
My attempt:
$\exists$ $(p,w)$, $(p',w')$ : $(p.x(p',w') \leq w) \land ((x(p',w') \neq x(p,w))$ $\land$ $(p'.x(p,w)\leq w')$
Is this correct and how to write the negation statement in English language similar to how it is written in book.

The first inequality in the definition should have been $p\cdot x(p',w')\le w$.

thanks corrected

The first inequality in the negation should correspondingly be corrected. Then all look good.

thanks @HerrK. , corrected

Your definition of WARP needs correction.
The Walrasian demand function $x(p,w)$ satisfies the weak axiom of revealed preference if the following property holds:
$(\forall (p,w), (p',w'))(( p\cdot x(p',w')\leq w \ \wedge \ x(p',w')\neq x(p,w))\Rightarrow p'\cdot x(p,w)>w')$
The negation of WARP can be written as the following property:
$(\exists (p,w), (p',w'))(( p\cdot x(p',w')\leq w \ \wedge \ x(p',w')\neq x(p,w))\wedge p'\cdot x(p,w)\leq w')$

Thanks, corrected. Could you help me with same definition but in context of choice structure:
If for some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ with $x,y \in B$ we have $x \in C(B)$, then for any $B' \in \mathcal{B}$ with $x,y \in B'$ and $y \in \ C(B')$, we must also have $x \in C(B')$

Do you want its negation?

yes  , because i want to know what conditions come under antecedent and for WARP to be vacuously the antecedent must include conditions upto ...$y \in C(B')$

Here is the negation of WARP: There exist $B,B'\in\mathcal{B}$ and there exist $x,y\in B\cap B'$ such that $x\in C(B)$, $y\in C(B')$ but $x\notin C(B')$.

Definition of WARP is $(\forall B, B'\in\mathcal{B})(\forall x,y\in B\cap B')((x\in C(B)\wedge y\in C(B'))\Rightarrow x\in C(B'))$

Thanks alot @Amit Sir
